# Write wxListBox to .txt file in Python

Tags: python-2.7, loops, wxpython, writetofile

I have a wxListBox filled with strings. I would like to write the contents of my wxListBox to a .txt file.

I have tried:

```
def saveDB(self, parent):

    listBox = ""
    for i in range(self.listBox.GetCount()):
        listBox = self.listBox.GetString(i) + "\n"
```

This does not seem to be getting the job done. How can I write the contents to a .txt file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
listBox = ""
    for i in range(self.listBox.GetCount()):
        listBox = self.listBox.GetString(i) + "\n"
```

This just got the listbox content into a 'listBox' variable.

You need to write to a file, something like this should do.

```
f = open('yourfile.txt', 'w')
f.write(listBox)
f.close()
```

Comment: This worked great, thanks @Werner appreciate the help!